# Creating a new type with a generic parameter as literal field name

Tags: typescript

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish :

```js
type Selection<K, T> = {
  selectionDate: string;
  selector: User;
  [K]: T
}

// Then :

type NodeSelection = Selection<"node", Node>
type ParamSelection = Selection<"param", Param>
// etc.
```

But it doesn't work that way seemingly. How should I proceed ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [intersect](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) your object type of static keys with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) representing the dynamic key, like this:

```
  type Selection<K extends PropertyKey, T> = {
    selectionDate: string;
    selector: User;
  } & { [P in K]: T }
```

Note that `K` has to be [constrained](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a keylike type (`PropertyKey` is an alias for `string | number | symbol`).

That gives you the following types:

```
  type NodeSelection = Selection<"node", Node>
  /* type NodeSelection = {
       selectionDate: string;
       selector: User;
     } & { node: Node; } */

  type ParamSelection = Selection<"param", Param>
  /* type ParamSelection = {
       selectionDate: string;
      selector: User;
     } & { param: Param; }*/
```

You can verify that this should work the way you expect.

There are other ways to write `Selection`, such as using the built-in [`Record<K,T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) and even ways to [avoid the intersection via a single mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJIAuAnjMgKpQQBOSAvHkqJAFxJRkMCWwAOZIAvgG4S5KsgAKIBuBZs4isN14DhYyYSRTK1JAGUIGCPDL8A9sAA8AaSQQAHmQjAAJlCSyG16gZKBwgKABokABUAPmUCPVIkAG1ZJEEkJwAfJAAienNLG2AAERB3HKRsvLMLMmsGHIBdTilSVNd3Lx9qgqtbUvKkAH4ePkERFoS25zcPb1z82vqKkbpGJEnEqLEiAxkkADlrTwhTXqLlM9qiuxzgY4gciKOT6KkAegAqaSMX05rCrY4q1EotASUyhANGNhLotqQwXUGNw1gw4fD7iduH90aIkJ93rsEoY5ApwFdwZcAX17DlVOAnr4yWA3gkvj9SWoKTTgVMtoiigMoaMtEJ0fDEfUUfQ0SDEvT1Ey1OK8QSiaIgA), but the above should meet your needs.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJFJIAuAnjMgKpQQBOSAvHkqJAFxJTmMBLYAHMkAXwDcpCtWQAFEI3Ct2cJWB59BI8VMLSqNJAGUIGCPHICA9sAA8AaSQQAHuQjAAJlCRzG1mkYqBwhKABokABUAPhUCYjJeMwsrWwAREHdNfiFhPUSk80trRh56JnzxJAAydgBtOSQhJAcAXR5I8SJpAHoeqIALDyQuboTDZAA5a08IUyLU4BV5lJt7ACJgGYh1iOnZ6N6AKhkjfbnkyzW46QLC1fTMiGztPNuChgWSsoZGSsSxDV2FtZjxzhIqkcemMyBNfIpwCsrrZlpdFnZ1mpwLt4epDgkeic4Qp1EjFjcEndPg9gBksrwciJ-olqcVSkhyn93lVargkFiNLjwBCxFCxmIgA)